# PhoneGap ignores viewport tag with specific width set?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have developed a webapp and successfully used the viewport element to fit the app for different devices. On iPhone for example i used this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=685,user-scalable=0" />
```

My webapp looks fine with this viewport on the iPhone Safari browser. Therefore i thought, it would be easy to wrap my webapp with the help of PhoneGap as an AppStore App. But so far i had no luck to do so. The viewport tag seems to be ignored completely.

So here is my question:
**Does the viewport tag work at all with a specific width (like in the above example) on PhoneGap?** Or do i have to rework everything to responsive web design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been fighting with the same for a few hours.
With the last version of phonegap i managed like this :

In your main java, add the following lines BEFORE super.loadUrl(blablabla

```
    super.init(); 
    super.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    super.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

This still will allow the user to "double tap" to zoom in/out. So modify your meta with this :

<meta name="viewport" content="width=685; target-density-dpi=device-dpi ; initial-scale=0.1; maximum-scale=0.1; user-scalable=no;" />

It worked for me with Phonegap 3.0, and Android >= 4

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta tag like this to set the width automatically to device width:

```
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But i do not want to set it to device-width. I want to set it to exactly 685px.

Comment: Can you please tell your user case for fixing it to 685px?

Comment: I have developed a mobile website bassed on the desktop version of our site. The main column of our desktop site is 685px. I want to display exactly this column for mobile. Therefore i am just delivering the html for this column and want the viewport to be 685px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the header of html

```
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

and this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
 < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=yes; initial-scale=0.1; maximum-scale=5; minimum-scale=0.5" />
```